# MATLAB mex routine does not return correct value

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to build a C/C++ function for MATLAB to call. Here is my C/C++ code:

```
#include "mex.h"

double* MyarrayProduct(double* a, double* b, int N)
{
    double* c = (double*)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    double* pc = c;

    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        *pc = *a**b;
        pc++;
        a++;
        b++;
    }

    return c;
}

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

    //------------------------------------------ Verify MEX-File Input and Output Parameters -----------------------------------------------------//
    //To check for two input arguments, multiplier and inMatrix, use this code.
    if(nrhs!=2) 
    {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:nrhs",
                      "Two inputs required.");
    }

    //Use this code to check for one output argument, the product outMatrix.
    if(nlhs!=1) 
    {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:nlhs",
                          "One output required.");
    }

    if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[1]) || 
         mxIsComplex(prhs[1])) 
    {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notDouble",
            "Input matrix must be type double.");
    }

    /* check that number of rows in second input argument is 1 */
    if(mxGetM(prhs[1])!=1) 
    {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notRowVector",
                          "Input must be a row vector.");
    }


    //------------------------------------------ variable declarations here ----------------------------------------//
    double *inMatrixA;      /* input scalar */
    double *inMatrixB;       /* 1xN input matrix */

    int ncols;           /* size of matrix */

    double *outMatrix;      /* output matrix */


    //------------------------------------------- read in data -----------------------------------------//
    /* get the value of the scalar input  */
    inMatrixA =  mxGetPr(prhs[0]);


    /* create a pointer to the real data in the input matrix  */
    inMatrixB = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);


    /* get dimensions of the input matrix */
    ncols = mxGetN(prhs[1]);


    //------------------------------------------- Prepare Output Data -----------------------------------------//
    /* create the output matrix */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,ncols,mxREAL);

    /* get a pointer to the real data in the output matrix */
    outMatrix = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    /* call the computational routine */
    outMatrix = MyarrayProduct(inMatrixA,inMatrixB,ncols);


/* code here */
}
```

Here is my MATLAB reuslts.

```
>> a =[1 2 3]

a =

     1     2     3

>> b = [4 5 6]

b =

     4     5     6

>> mex MyarrayProduct.cpp
>> c = MyarrayProduct(a,b)

c =

     0     0     0
```

I stepped in my C/C++ code, and found at

```
outMatrix = MyarrayProduct(inMatrixA,inMatrixB,ncols);
```

`outMatrix` is actually 4, 10, 18, which is correct. But it seems it has trouble send results back. I am wondering what is the problem here? I cannot return a pointer in mex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,ncols,mxREAL);
```

On the line above the `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` call has already allocated a matrix of size `1 x ncols` for you.

```
outMatrix = MyarrayProduct(inMatrixA,inMatrixB,ncols);
```

All you're doing here is over-writing the value of `outMatrix`, i.e. the memory location where it points. You're not actually overwriting the memory that `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` allocated.

---

To fix the problem change your `MyarrayProduct()` function to:

```
void MyarrayProduct(double* a, double* b, int N, double* pc)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        *pc = *a**b;
        pc++;
        a++;
        b++;
    }
}
```

And then call it as

```
/* call the computational routine */
MyarrayProduct(inMatrixA,inMatrixB,ncols,outMatrix);
```

---

Another solution that should work, while leaving `MyarrayProduct()` unchanged (mostly) is this:

```
/* create the output matrix */
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,0,mxREAL); // don't allocate any memory yet

/* call the computational routine */
outMatrix = MyarrayProduct(inMatrixA,inMatrixB,ncols);

/* free the existing real array (in case MATLAB allocates a size 0 array) */
mxFree(mxGetPr(plhs[0]));

/* reassign the array in the matrix */
mxSetPr(plhs[0], outMatrix);

/* set the correct dimensions */
mxSetN(plhs[0], ncols);
```

However, even in this case, I'd modify `MyarrayProduct()` so that it is using [`mxMalloc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxmalloc.html) instead of `malloc`. The linked MathWorks documentation warns you against using the latter.

> Use `mxMalloc` instead of the ANSI C `malloc` function to allocate memory in MATLAB applications.

Comment: I know your code works, but how about this line?

    /* get a pointer to the real data in the output matrix */
    outMatrix = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

Doesn't this point outMatrix to plhs[0]? So if outMatrix changes, shouldn't plhs[0] change as well?

Comment: @Ono No, all you're doing there is reassigning pointers, not copying what the pointer points to. This is essentially what your code does - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbba1c936f3e1883